# mix.browserSync() loading forever and not displaying my blade

Tags: php, laravel, webpack, laravel-5.5, laravel-mix

I am trying to setup dev environment using laravel5.5.

I added `mix.browserSync('mytestapp.dev')` in my webpack.mix.js and ran following commands `npm install` & `npm run watch`.

SASS and JS files got complied successfully but http://localhost:3000/ ('browsersync url) keeps on loading forever.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console on your browser?

Comment: Did you find a solution this? Having a similar issue: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/elixir/laravel-mix-and-browsersync-hot-module-replacement-not-working-do-i-need-to-setup-localhostports